# DROP & CREATE FUNCTION improved performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a query that was using a multi-statement table valued function in a WHERE clause as such:

```
WHERE value IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('SO',','))
```

The return value of the function is a table with a single cell, 'SO'

I found the query to be much quicker without the function:

```
WHERE value = 'SO'
WHERE value IN ('SO')
WHERE value IN (SELECT 'SO')
```

Eventually I dropped and created the function without changing any code and the query ran much faster. Before, it wouldn't complete in a minute and now it takes a second.

What might have changed when I dropped and recreated the function?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server compiles queries in stored functions and stored procedures the first time they are called. The decisions made by the optimizer are based on the table statistics and parameters at that time.

This is called *parameter sniffing* (I'm not a fan of that term, because the decisions are based both on parameters and table statistics).

Your experience suggests that the query plan was suboptimal -- that would usually be the difference between a hash-based join and a nested loop join. Sometimes, you can fix this by using an index.

Another common fix is to force recompilation of the query (or queries) in the programming code. However, that incurs the overhead of recompilation. Such overhead should be small for a query that takes a minute to run, but is more significant if the query takes less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CROSS APPLY` instead of `IN` clause :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('SO',',') 
    ) tt
WHERE t.value = tt.col;
```

If you have a `string` which has large no_sos then `IN` clause would give you poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Tally Tables instead of UDF

```
declare @mytbl table (Value varchar(100))
insert into @mytbl values('Element01'),('Element04')

DECLARE @Parameter VARCHAR(8000)
    SET @Parameter = ',Element01,'

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tally') is not null
drop table dbo.tally

select TOP (select len(@Parameter)) identity(INT,1,1) AS N INTO TALLY FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,Master.dbo.SysColumns  c2

select * from @mytbl **where Value in (SELECT sUBSTRING(@Parameter,N+1,CHARINDEX(',',@Parameter,n+1)-n-1)
   FROM dbo.Tally
  WHERE N <= LEN(@Parameter)-1
    AND SUBSTRING(@Parameter,N,1) = ','
  )**
```